# Как убрать виртуальную клавиатуру в kivy Python?

Tags: python, kivy

При нажатии на поле ввода(InputText) появляеться виртуальная клавиатура из-за этого я не вижу часть окна.Искал в интернете но не нашёл как убрать эту клавиатуру при нажатии на поле ввода.